# How to restart a program automatically

Tags: automation, reboot

I´m using

- Windows 7 Ultimate
- Flash Media Live Encoder (FME)

I´m using a cmd file to start FME, the file (watch.cmd) points to the Flash Media Encoder.exe file, and also to the profile with the settings FME are using.

In order to manually restart this application, I just close the cmd file, and then clic on it again.

So, I want to

- Shut down my watch.cmd file every day, 9:00 a.m.
- Restart watch.cmd right after, if was closed previously.

Is there a way?

Comment: I smell XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to write a small script in a language such as [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to handle it. Then you'd run your AutoIt script whenever you want to start FMLE instead of your watch.cmd file.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add "shutdown /r" to the task scheduler and then add your "watch.cmd" to the startup group (maybe using a .bat file to add your command line params.  There are other ways to do this, but this is probably the simplest.

you could probably start FME as a service as well. But you'd need to read up on "running an application as a windows service".  (Not really for the faint of heart).

Answer (score 0):

Use [BDV SystemEvents](http://www.bdvnotepad.com/products/bdv-systemevents/) application, it allows to run any application when another application is closed. But if you will specify the same application as a Condition as well as an Action you will get what you want.